# Blanked page after deploy on gh-pages, using travis

Tags: vue.js, travis-ci, github-pages, vue-cli-3

I really stuck in how to create a `gh-pages` in `vue CLI 3`.

I have a project: https://github.com/aniaska4/Playlist,

I followed this instruction: [travis](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#pwa).

So I add `.travis.yml` :

```
 language: node_js
 node_js:
 - "node"

 cache: npm

script: npm run build

deploy:
provider: pages
skip_cleanup: true
github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN_Movies
local_dir: dist
on:
 branch: master
```

Also I add `deploy.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# abort on errors
set -e

# build
npm run build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd dist

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
# echo 'www.example.com' > CNAME

git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io
# git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git master

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
git push -f https://github.com/aniaska4/Playlist.git master:gh-pages

cd -
```

In `vue.config.js` I add:

```
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? '/Playlist/'
  : '/',
```

Next I did a deploy by `travis CI`, which was successful. But when my `gh-pages` created I have a blanked page and errors in console. https://aniaska4.github.io/Playlist/

[image]

In network it looks like this:

[image]

Am I right that there is wrong Request URL? It should be: https://aniaska4.github.io/Playlist/ I have really no idea how to fix. Any idea?

Comment: no help ? :( maybe somebody know the solution. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, there is nothing wrong with the deployment itself, and your assets are [available from the Player directory](https://aniaska4.github.io/Playlist/js/app.8e64359d.js) of your GitHub pages. The reason why your `vue-cli` application can't resolve the assets properly is, environment variables that not prefixed with `VUE_APP_` can't be recognized on script files, [as stated on the documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables).

Considering the above situation, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is always a falsey value and it causes `publicPath` to be `/` on each environment. You should use env files for different environments to define your variables.

First, create a `.env.local` file on your root directory of your project with the content below. These variables will be loaded for your local development. (`npm run serve`)

```
VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH="/"
```

Then create your `.env.production` file again in the root project directory. These will be injected when you make a production build. (`npm run dist`, therefore `vue-cli-service build --mode production`)

```
VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH="/Playlist/"
```

Finally, change the `publicPath` key in your `vue.config.js` file to get injected Vue environment variables:

```js
publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH
```

Deploy your project again, and you'll see that your publicPath is changed with the production path and your assets will be loaded as intended.

Comment: That is amazing! It works! I spent so many days to solve my problems and I didn't know how. Thank you soooo much. You made my day :)